# Do other OS's support ALT-codes?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, input, alt-code

Do OS's other than Windows support Alt-codes? If I put in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for ☺, would I be able to put the same code in on MacOS and Linux and get the same output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alt-code is Windows specific. Other OSes have various ways to input Unicode characters.

On macOS 8.5 and later you hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> then type the 4-digit hex value. Characters outside the BMP can be input via Character Viewer

On Linux there are 2 common methods:

- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and type u followed by the hex digits.
- Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, release, then type the hex digits, and press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Space</kbd> or press and release <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)

There are other ways that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input)

---

There are also other cross-platform methods to type any Unicode characters

- Open the rich text editor on your platform like MS Word, Libre Office or Wordpad, enter the hex code point value (like 1F3BB) with an optional `U+` prefix and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Open the console in your browser and run the below commands. It works in most modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome/Chromium (including Chromium Edge)

  ```js
  copy("\u25A0")    // only applicable for characters in the BMP (⩽ U+FFFF)
  copy("\u{1F3BB}") // applicable for all characters (U+0000 to U+10FFFF)
  copy(String.fromCodePoint(0x1F3BB))
  ```
- Use PowerShell to copy the desired character to clipboard

  ```powershell
  scb "`u{1F3BB}"                                   # or
  Set-Clipboard "`u{1F3BB}"                         # or
  [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F3BB) | Set-Clipboard # or
  [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F3BB) | scb           # or
  [char]0x1F3BB | Set-Clipboard
  ```