# Is There Any Difference Between the Alt+7 Or Alt+0149 Bullet Symbol?

Tags: keyboard, operating-systems, unicode, typing, alt-code

If I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and press <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, then <kbd>9</kbd>, I get a bullet (•).

If I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press <kbd>7</kbd>, I get a bullet (•).

I've been doing it the first way, but recently came across the second keyboard shortcut. Both seem to work and give the same result.

Practically speaking, have I just been wasting keystrokes, or is there a reason to use one key combination versus the other? Do they both work on different operating systems, or is one more reliable than the other?

Comment: If none of these key combinations is not reassigned/captured on the OS or application level then both methods produces the symbol with the same charcode. Tested on Windows 10 (including command line).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the first numpad key defines the type of code page to use

- If it's <kbd>numpad 1-9</kbd> then the [DOS code page (A.K.A OEM code page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#MS-DOS_code_pages) will be used

  The default OEM code page on US Windows is [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), so if you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> then code point 7 in CP437  (which is U+2022 `•` if you check the CP437 table in the previous link) will be typed in
- If it's <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> then the [Windows code page (A.K.A ANSI code page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page) will be used

  By default the Windows code page is [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set) on US Windows. So if you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> then code point 149 in CP1252 will be typed in, which is also a U+2022 bullet

  In fact Alt code originates from the DOS era, and people are so used to the Alt code in DOS that Microsoft can't break it when they use ANSI code pages in Windows and must differentiate the two with the `0` prefix
- If it's <kbd>numpad +</kbd> then input is hexadecimal UCS2/UTF-16

  Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> gives you the same bullet character

  Note that this requires the [hexnumpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Transition_to_Unicode) to be enabled by setting a `REG_SZ` value with name `EnableHexNumpad` in the `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method` registry key then reboot

See also [Which character encoding is used for ALT-codes?](https://superuser.com/q/348674/241386)

---

> Practically speaking, have I just been wasting keystrokes, or is there a reason to use one key combination versus the other?

They're all the same, so use the shorter one to save keystrokes

> Do they both work on different operating systems,

Alt codes are Windows-specific. Other OSes use different ways to enter arbitrary characters. For more details read [Do other OS's support ALT-codes?](https://superuser.com/q/1144949/241386)

> or is one more reliable than the other?

Only hex numpad with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is reliable because it enters Unicode characters. Different languages use different ANSI and OEM code pages by default, and both can be changed easily so the output may differ from one computer to another if you use the normal decimal Alt code