# Notepad++, entering Unicode characters

Tags: notepad++, unicode, alt-code

I'm trying to type Unicode characters in Notepad++ (v7.8.4), and it isn't working. This procedure should enter a Unicode character: Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press the numeric keypad's <kbd>+</kbd> key, then enter the Unicode character's four-digit code on the numeric keypad (using the main keyboard for A-F).

When I do this, at least a couple of different things happen, depending on the character I tried to enter.

1. With *"discretionary hyphen"* (U+00AD): When I enter the fourth digit, Notepad++ opens a pop-up menu which asks whether I want the character to be defined in English, multiple languages, etc. I select "multiple languages." The menu closes. At this point the character should appear in the file, but it does not. Character encoding UTF-8 is selected; I have selected *View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters*; Notepad++ shows special characters for CR/LF, etc., but none for the Unicode characters I tried to enter.
2. With *"dollar sign"* (U+0024): The `+` appears in text, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>. This is exactly what should happen if I try to enter an ASCII character through the numeric keypad (<kbd>Alt</kbd> with numeric keypad '024').

In other posts I saw that some users prefer to enter special characters through *Run > Charmap*, but my Notepad++ has no such menu entry.

What is happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> This procedure should enter a Unicode character: Hold down Alt, press the numeric keypad's + key, then enter the Unicode character's four-digit code on the numeric keypad (using the main keyboard for A-F)

This only works if you enable the hex numpad by creating a registry entry named `EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method`, set its value to `1` then reboot. If not enabled then you can only enter [characters in the OEM and ANSI code pages](https://superuser.com/a/1666633/241386). That's why you see the final character similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>024</kbd> when typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+0024</kbd>

There are also other ways to enter arbitrary Unicode characters in Notepad++ that you can find in [Notepad++ inserting special Unicode characters in UTF-8](https://superuser.com/a/983998/241386)

---

> In other posts I saw that some users prefer to enter special characters through Run > Charmap, but my Notepad++ has no such menu entry

*Run > Charmap* here has nothing to do with Notepad++. It means open the Run dialog (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), type `charmap` then enter to run charmap.exe. Alternatively just open Start menu, search for *character map* and open

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the decimal values. From the examples you have given:

1. `U+0024`: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0036</kbd>
2. `U+00AD`: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0173</kbd>

Regarding Run > Charmap, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Run</kbd>, type Charmap press OK. Charmap will open, then you can search for your character, copy it, then paste it on Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

> In other posts I saw that some users prefer to enter special characters through *Run → Charmap*, but my Notepad++ has no such menu entry.

Regarding the Windows Character Map utility specifically, it's probably worth mentioning that you do not need to use e.g. the Windows `Run` dialog to run this program.

That is, Notepad++ can run arbitrary programs with its own `Run` menu entry. Simply select *Run → Run...* then the insert the path to Character Map in the `Run...` dialog i.e.:

```
%windir%\system32\charmap.exe
```

**Example:**

[image]

Click *Save...* to create a `Run` menu entry (e.g. "Open Character Map") and the utility should then be available to be run via Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: I decided that enabling the hex numpad was the best solution for my purposes. I followed phuclv's instructions and can now enter a number with Alt+nnnn. But it's a *decimal* number, not hex! Alt+0033 displays '!'. Alt+002d displays nothing, but the 'D' passes through as Alt+D. I can solve my problem now, but I still have a mystery -- can anyone explain it?

Comment: Wait, this isn't working. When I enter the characters I want, I get nonsense. With "Show All Characters" enabled: A+8205 (U+200D, zero space joiner) displays '?'. Alt+8209 (U+2011, no-break hyphen) displays '?'. Alt+0160 (U+00A0, no-break space) displays a space at the *end* of the line, no matter where the insert point was. Alt+0173 (U+00AD, discretionary hyphen) displays an ordinary hyphen. When I enter the same codes into Notepad (not ++) I get a musical note, a left arrowhead, a space, and a hyphen. If I copy them & paste into Notepad++, I get ' ?-?', This is more complex than I thought.